# Connection to mongodb on docker does not work via mongoose

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose, database-connection

I'm trying to set up mongodb server via docker and connect to it through express.js api using mongoose. However, api does not connect, but browser does.

I tried already changing configurations, restarting docker, reinstalling node_modules.
Also i tried variety of connection strings:

```
mongodb://localhost:8081/db/movies
mongodb://localhost:8081/
mongodb://localhost:8081/movies
```

My docker-compose:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    container_name: mongo-express
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
```

Fragment of core, responsible for connecting to database:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:8081/db/movies', { useNewUrlParser: true }).then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to Database");
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Not Connected to Database ERROR! ", err);
});
```

Moongose version is 5.4.21.

Expected to get connection to database, but actual result is:

```
Not Connected to Database ERROR!  { MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to localhost:8081 closed
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\moviesapi\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:276:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:567:12)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple mistakes which cause the error. If you read your code again, you will see the first issue which you are trying to connect `mongodb://localhost:8081` which is MongoDB's administration panel. So, you need to connect to `mongodb://localhost:27017` which is MongoDB's default port.

Also, you **must** update your `docker-compose.yml` because `8082` is not the default port for MongoDB.

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
```

You can learn more information about your stack with reading documentation, searching in the Internet.